# Get Pixel Values along several lines from a mask which is tilted

Tags: c++, opencv

currently I have segmented the object (rectangular) and now I want to create a Line profile. I dont know how to get along this line.

[detected object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dx75.png)

Aim is to get this:

[object with lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Slpz3.png)

Update 14:25:

I know already the angle from the bounding rect and used this to calculate the shift in y-direction in order to rearrange the values to a new mat so that I only need go through the matrix to get a line profile.

Here my Code, but the rearrangement did not work.

```
Mat imgIn(SizeY, SizeX, CV_16U, &Wire[0]), 
imgOut(SizeY, SizeX, CV_16U, Scalar(0)), 
temp, drawing, mask, lineProfile(SizeY, SizeX, CV_16U, Scalar(0));

vector<vector<Point>> contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

Point center;

char buffer[100];

bool found = false;
int rect_no (0);
double angle(0.0);

// Detecting outer contours

    temp = ::adaptiveThreshold(imgIn, SizeY, SizeX, kernelSize, thresh, 0);

     // Find contours
    findContours(temp, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CHAIN_APPROX_TC89_KCOS, Point(0, 0) );

    /// Find the rotated rectangles and ellipses for each contour
    vector<RotatedRect> minRect( contours.size() );

    for( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ ) minRect[i] = minAreaRect( Mat(contours[i]) );

    // Draw contours + rotated rects
    drawing = Mat::zeros(temp.size(), CV_8U );
    Point2f rect_points[4];

    for( int i = 0; i< minRect.size(); i++ ){

        if((float)minRect[i].boundingRect().height/(float)minRect[i].boundingRect().width > 3.0 && (float)minRect[i].boundingRect().height/(float)minRect[i].boundingRect().width < 4.9){      

            // rotated rectangle
             minRect[i].points(rect_points);
            for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++) line(drawing, rect_points[j], rect_points[(j+1)%4], Scalar(255), 1, 8);
            //found = minRect[i].boundingRect().contains(Point(459, 512));
            if(minRect[i].boundingRect().area() > 1000)
            rect_no = i;
        }
    }
 center = computeCentroid(drawing);
 cv::floodFill(drawing, center, cv::Scalar(255));

 drawing.convertTo(imgOut, CV_16U, 257.0);
 imgIn.copyTo(imgOut, drawing);

 // Calculate Wire SR_min

 // Get angle of Wire
 angle = (90 - (-1 * minRect[rect_no].angle))*(CV_PI/180);

 for(int i = 0;i < SizeY;i++){
    for(int j = 0;j < SizeX;j++){
        if(imgOut.at<ushort>(i, j) != 0)
        lineProfile.at<ushort>(i, j) = imgOut.at<ushort>((unsigned short)(i/cos(angle)), j);

    }
 }


for(int i = 0;i < SizeY;i++){
    for(int j = 0;j < SizeX;j++){

            *Wire++ = lineProfile.at<ushort>(i, j);//imgOut.at<ushort>(i, j);

    }
}
```

Comment: use minAreaRect to find the rotation angle and draw the lines withing that coordinate system.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the coordinates of the beginning and the end of your line, getting the values at each point on the line should be easy with OpenCV's [LineIterator](http://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/dd2/classcv_1_1LineIterator.html). Feed it your image and your two points and let it work its magic.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to binarize the detected object image , then you could possibly able to apply Houghlines function of OpenCv . You can find it in the below link 
http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html